# How do I connect to an online server using Android Studio in an Java app? (API 28)

Tags: java, php, android, server, registration

I am trying to register from a Java Developed app on Android Studio on this online server.
I have created BackgroundWork class that extends AsyncTask. I have a really big issue with this class. I have tried so many times to debug it but found no errors. Can you give me a suggestion or can you show me how it is done?

This is the BackgroundWork class:

```
public class BackgroundWork extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {


    Context context;
    //use this for mail. Create other contructors for other tasks
    public BackgroundWork(Context context){
        this.context = context;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        //write code here
        String method = params[0];
        if(method.equals("register")){
            String username = params[1];
            String nume = params[2];
            String prenume = params[3];
            String pass = params[4];
            String login = params[5];
            String date = params[6];
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = null;
            try{
                URL url = new URL("http://gladiaholdings.com/PHP/register.php");
                httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                int responseCode = httpURLConnection.getResponseCode();
                if(responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK){

                    httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                    httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-httpd-php");

                    httpURLConnection.setReadTimeout(14000);
                    httpURLConnection.setConnectTimeout(14000);
                    httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);

                    OutputStream OS = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();

                    String data = URLEncoder.encode("username", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(username,"UTF-8") + "&" +
                            URLEncoder.encode("nume","UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(nume,"UTF-8") + "&" +
                            URLEncoder.encode("prenume","UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(prenume,"UTF-8") + "&" +
                            URLEncoder.encode("pass", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(pass,"UTF-8") + "&" +
                            URLEncoder.encode("date","UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(date,"UTF-8") + "&" +
                            URLEncoder.encode("sex","UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode("0", "UTF-8");
                    String regex = "[0-9]+";
                    if(login.matches(regex))
                        data = data + URLEncoder.encode("nrtel", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(login,"UTF-8") + "&" +
                                URLEncoder.encode("mail","UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode("-null-","UTF-8");
                    else
                        data = data + URLEncoder.encode("mail", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(login,"UTF-8") + "&" +
                                URLEncoder.encode("nrtel","UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode("-null-","UTF-8");

                    BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(OS,"UTF-8"));
                    bufferedWriter.write(data);
                    bufferedWriter.flush();
                    bufferedWriter.close();
                    OS.close();
                    InputStream IS = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                    IS.close();
                    Toast.makeText(context, data,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return "Registration successful";
                }
                else Toast.makeText(context, "The server is down", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch (MalformedURLException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
                return "Bad URL";
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return "IOExeption";
            }
        }

        return "Error, u noob!";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        Toast.makeText(context,result,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

And this is the script register.php: (which I have tested on the server and works perfectly):

```
<?php

include 'server.php';

$username = $_POST['username'];
$nume = $_POST['nume'];
$prenume = $_POST['prenume'];
$pass = $_POST['pass'];
$mail = $_POST['mail'];
$nastere = $_POST['nastere'];
$sex = $_POST['sex'];
$nrtel = $_POST['nrtel'];


$server = new Server();
$server -> register($username,$nume,$prenume,$pass,$mail,$nastere,$sex,$nrtel);

?>
```

I have managed to realise the error, though. It is an IOException. Weird fact: If I comment on everything and leave only the URL initialisation, then there are no errors. But, If I write any line of code after that, then the app crashes (for Toast) or gives an IOExeption (for getResponseCode() function).

Comment: Not familiar with Java that much but `httpURLConnection.getResponseCode()` seems to imply that `openConnection` is actually performing a request. If that's the case then that request would certainly fail since it won't have (at that point) any of the POST data. Again, not familiar with Java, but might be something worth looking into

Comment: Thanks, but in all the tutorials they start with that command